# nunjucks: Error: template not found, Problems with directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, nunjucks

Sorry if I report with a problem that has been dealt with frequently in the forum.
I get the error message that the template was not found.

Error: template not found: D:\Development\src\nunjucks\pages\templates\text.njk

What am I doing wrong with the directory structure specification?
Is there a way how to generate html files from nunjucks files like gulp? With gulp it works.

This is the script for node.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

app.use(express.static('dist'));

nunjucks.configure('src/nunjucks', {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app,
  watch: true
});

app.engine ('njk', nunjucks.render);
app.set('view engine', 'njk');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/index2');
  console.log("index");
})

server.listen(3010, () => {
  console.log('http://localhost:' + 3010);
})
```

And this is the directory structure:

```
app.js
gulpfile.js
|-src
|  |-nunjucks
|    |-pages
|    |    index.njk
|    |-templates
|         text.njk
```

And this is the index.njk file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Header Test</h1>
  {% include "text.njk" %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `{% include "templates/text.njk" %}` or ``{% include "../templates/text.njk" %}``

Answer (score 1):

All your templates will be resolved from the path(s) you a passing to `nunjucks.configure`.

In your case you should include template with path from `src/nunjucks`.

E.g.`templates/text.njk`.

Answer (score 0):

That is the solution in the script for node.js

```
nunjucks.configure('src/nunjucks', {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app,
  cache: false,
  watch: true
});

// app.set('views', 'src/nunjucks/pages');
app.engine ('njk', nunjucks.render);
app.set('view engine', 'njk');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/index.njk');
})

app.get('/index.html', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/index.njk');
})
```

And the index.html file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Header Test</h1>
    {% include "../templates/text.njk" %}
</body>
</html>
```